# Karnaugh Veitch diagram and ordering of the variables

Tags: digital-logic

I have a little problem understanding the ordering of the variables at the axis.

For example, at the lecture we did 4 variable Karnaugh Veitch diagram as a

```
    A
  0 1 1 0
C 1     0
  1     1 D
  0 0 1 1
      B
```

On this site I found it like this(page 5)
http://sus.ziti.uni-heidelberg.de/Lehre/DSTVorlesung1213/DST_Fischer_05_KMAPs.pdf

```
      A
  0 0 1 1
D 1     0
  1     1 c
  0 1 1 1
     B
```

And examples here are also different.
http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Karnaugh-Veitch-Diagramm:_Theorie_des_KV-Diagramms

0 represents logical not, 1 represents normal

Can somebody explain or refer me to a website/book where I can find out, how to put variables on the right place at the axis.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower K-map is wrong:

```
      A
  0 0 1 1
D 1     0
  1     1 c
  0 1 1 1
     B
```

It can better be drawn as:

```
       A
    0 0 1 1
  0 _ _ _ _ 0
D 1 _ _ _ _ 0
  1 _ _ _ _ 1 C
  0 _ _ _ _ 1
    0 1 1 0
       B
```

The goal is to have a unique combination of variables for each cell in the matrix. It doesn't really matter which variable goes where, as long as you get the distribution right. For both horizontal axis you can either use:

- (top) | (bottom)
- 0011 and 0110

or

- 1100 and 0110

or

- 0011 and 1001

or

- 1100 and 1001

or

- 0110 and 0011

or

- 1001 and 0011

or

- 0110 and 1100

or

- 1001 and 1100

As long as you carefully check which combination of variables is related to every single cell. Same goes for the vertical two axis.

[image]

Comment: Was it the three 1's along the B side that made it wrong?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, and I spotted a typo in mine too ...

Answer (score 1):

The K-maps you show are functionally identical - yes they look a little different but if you draw each one and apply all 16 ABCD states to each map you'll see that each of the 16 states do not overlap any other state on both maps.

Comment: Identical except for the three '1's on B and C in the second...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Can I assume that a one in a corner is only allowed if the two adjacent edges share that 1 meaningfully?

Comment: Probably. Sharing the corner symbols seems like an odd way of drawing K-maps to me and possibly confusing.